# How to split a windows network?

Tags: windows, networking

I share internet with my neighbors, and I can see their PC names, so I want to split the network so that the computers in my house can communicate with each other, but not with the computers outside my house. The computers have Windows 7 and Windows 10. I am concerned of potential virus infection and confidentiality of shared files and data transmition through internet and network.

Comment: Get yourself 2 access points.  Separate the networks into separate  networks 10.x.x.X vs 192.x.x.x or get yourself a switch and create VLANs.

Comment: you really really want to do this at a hardware level, as Ramhound suggests. Software solutions are not sufficient to the concerns you raise about integrity and confidentiality.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you cannot "split" a network without the use of hardware. What is the arrangement between you and your neighbour? As Ramhound suggests, the best solution would probably be to purchase a cheap router and configure it so only you can access it. However, to be able to use it to access the Internet, its WAN port will need to be connected to one of the Ethernet ports on the shared router.

So, if the router is in your house, it's no problem, otherwise you might have to ask your neighbour if you can install a second router in his house that you can use. Though if your neighbour disagrees I think there are some routers/extenders/repeaters that wirelessly receive the Internet connection from the main router. Unfortunately I haven't had luck in doing so.